# Self-hosted NetTcp service timeout error

Tags: wcf, timeout, nettcpbinding, servicehost

I have a windows service which houses a WCF NetTcp host. From the client, when I start making calls to the service via tcp, they go through fine at first but then after a few minutes they all start to give the dreaded WCF timeout error which really has nothing to do with timeouts:

**This request operation sent to net.tcp://myserver:8080/ListingService did not receive a reply within the configured timeout (00:01:00).**

I've seen from other posts on this site that a lot of times this has to do with the max message sizes, but I've already set these to the limits to no avail.

Here is my windows service code:

```
public partial class Service : ServiceBase
    {
        internal static ServiceHost myHost = null;

        public Service()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 10000;
            //create host.
            var path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceHostAddress"].ToString();
            myHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(ListingService));
            //add endpoint.
            myHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IListingService), GetBinding(), path);
            //add behaviors.
            AddBehaviors();
            //open host.
            myHost.Open();
        }

        private void AddBehaviors()
        {
            //service metadata behavior.
            var smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
            myHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
            //service throttling behavior.
            var behavior = new ServiceThrottlingBehavior()
            {
                MaxConcurrentCalls = 10000,
                MaxConcurrentInstances = 10000,
                MaxConcurrentSessions = 10000
            };
            myHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(behavior);
            //service debug behavior.
            var serviceDebugBehavior = myHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>();
            serviceDebugBehavior.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true;
        }

        private Binding GetBinding()
        {
            var queueBinding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
            queueBinding.MaxConnections = 10000;
            queueBinding.MaxBufferSize = 2048000;
            queueBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2048000;
            return queueBinding;
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            if (myHost != null)
            {
                myHost.Close();
                myHost = null; 
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the client config in case it makes any difference:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>

      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding" transferMode="Buffered" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:01:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"><!-- transactionFlow="true"-->
          <security mode="None"/>
          <reliableSession enabled="false"/>
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>

    </bindings>
    <client>

      <endpoint
             address="net.tcp://myserver:8080/ListingService"
             binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding"
             contract="ListingServiceProxy.IListingService" name="NetTcpBinding" />

    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I make sure to close my client connections, here is the code:

```
public static void Using<T>(this T client, Action<T> work)
            where T : ICommunicationObject
        {
            try
            {
                work(client);
                client.Close();
            }
            catch (CommunicationException)
            {
                client.Abort();
                throw;
            }
            catch (TimeoutException)
            {
                client.Abort();
                throw;
            }
            catch
            {
                client.Abort();
                throw;
            }
        }

new ListingServiceClient().Using(client =>
                {
                    client.SaveListing(listing);
                });
```

Comment: Do you gracefully close the client proxy? This looks like service throttling behavior. Service throttling controls how many concurrent calls, sessions and instances can be handled by the ServiceHost. NetTcp is session oriented binding - each new client proxy creates new session and instance of the service which handles all request from the same proxy instance.

Comment: Hi @Ladislav Mrnka I added the client code above, which should close the client after every request. One question I had... would it make any different if I have reliable session enabled or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They ended up timing out because the database was actually timing out, it wasn't an issue with WCF.